# Mocking Linq2db DataConnection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, moq, xunit

Доброго времени суток!

Сегодня для написания Unit - тестов решил использовать фреймворк Moq.

Тестирую WebApi (.net core).
Тестовый фреймворк - xunit.

Столкнулся с проблемой разорвать порочную связь: контроллер-дб.

Пытался сделать Mock объекта ITable, но всё напрасно.
Перерыл все форумы и статьи.
Многие советуют уходить от Mock'инга DataConnection(DbContext) и делать всё через транзакции на живую в боевой БД.

Повторюсь, пишу Unit-тесты. А данные подходы являются полу интеграционными.

Вот допустим контроллер:

```
public class UserController 
{

   private DataManager db = null;

   public UserController(DataManager dataManager)
   {
      this.db= dataManager;
   }

   public JsonResult Get()
   {
      var userDb = db.User.ToList();

      var result = GetResponse(userDb); // Метод сериализующий данные в JsonResult 
      return result;
    }
}
```

DataManager представляет собой сгенерированную по существующей таблице T4 модель (класс), сущность которого передаётся в контроллер через DI:

```
public partial class DataManager : LinqToDB.Data.DataConnection
    {
        public ITable<User> User { get { return this.GetTable<User>(); } }

        partial void InitDataContext();
    }
```

**Вот данное свойство `DataManager.User` и не получается Mock'нуть
У кого нибудь получилось подсунуть вместо данного свойства ITable какой-нибудь List, который можно ручками для тестов составить(вместо коннекта к реальной бд)????**

На данный момент написал вот такой тест:

```
public class UserControllerTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public void TestGet()
        {
            // Arrange
            IEnumerable<User> expectedMas = new User[]
        {
            new User{ Id=1, Name= "q", Age=1, SurName= "q"},
            new User{ Id=2, Name= "w", Age=2, SurName= "w"}
        };

            var mock = new Mock<DataManager>();
            mock.Setup(usr => usr.User()).Returns(expectedMas); // Тут естественно ошибка компиляции, т.к. нельзя IEnumerable<User> привести к ITable<User>
            UserController controller = new UserController(mock.Object); 

            // Act
            var result = controller.Get() as IEnumerable<User>;

            // Assert
            Assert.NotNull(result);
            Assert.Equal(expectedMas, result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Я вижу 3 варианта: 1) делать как вы делаете, предоставив свою реализацию `ITable<>` (или переиспользовав ту, что пользует ваш контекст) 2) либо закрывать источники данных интерфейсами и мокать интерфейсы, 3) либо запускать каждый тест на отдельной временной БД, которую после теста удалять

Comment: Тоже об этом думал, но: 1) Переопределить ITable<>, значит практически переписать весь linq2db (Готовой реализации пр. Table<T> нет, точнее она есть, но она private) 2) Я показал лишь простой запрос, но есть и сложные, которые формирует как раз ITable<> и транслирует в sql, следовательно есть возможность переписать лишь пару методов, а выгрибать все данные из бд в память, и потом только делать выборку - не айс. 3) Слишком долго и затратно получается, + возможны конфликты с уже существующими локальными бд (т.к. проект пишу не я 1)

Comment: 2) я имел ввиду для каждого запроса сделать отдельный метод, или, если запросов оч много, сделать метод, что принимает делегат и возвращает данные. А траслировать делегат в sql уже внутри вашего реаозитория. 3) Для тестов временная БД может быть и локальной или даже просто БД в памяти